# Is it mandatory to configure PHP in order to scan configuration INI files on a per-directory basis(i.e. .htaccess files in my case) by PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, command-line-interface, configuration-files

I'm using **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit Operating System** on my machine.

I've installed the latest copy of **XAMPP server** on my machine which ships with **PHP 7.2.7**

I read following pages from the PHP Manual :

1. [Scan directories](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php#configuration.file.scan)
2. [.user.ini files](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php#configuration.file.per-user)

After reading the text from these two pages one doubt came to my mind :

To scan the configuration **INI files** on a per-directory basis(*in my case '.htaccess files'*) by PHP is it mandatory to run PHP on **CLI** with the `--with-config-file-scan-dir` option and then by overriding at run time by setting the `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` environment variable?

Or do such configuration **INI files** on a per-directory basis(*in my case '.htaccess files'*) get scan by PHP automatically?

If yes, then please explain me how the setting made in one environment(i.e. **CLI**) has effect in an entirely different environment(i.e. **SAPI**)?

If no, then please clear my confusion with some suitable example.

Comment: Per your first link it clearly says "It is **possible** to configure..." Is there a specific reason that you think it is mandatory? What are you trying to achieve that makes you think you need this?

Comment: Apache reads the `.htaccess` files. PHP does not use them, scan them or care about them

Comment: Also be careful as when/if you want to move a site from development to live, if you are using a hosting package, you will not get access to things like `.user.ini` files or the ability to mess with the configuration to this degree

Comment: @RiggsFolly : It's been clearly said in the manual that "Within each directory, PHP will scan all files ending in .ini in alphabetical order." "In addition to the main php.ini file, PHP scans for INI files in each directory". It means PHP scans .user.ini-style INI files(i.e. .htaccess files in my case)

Comment: CLI and Apache SAPI use different INI files by default. You can even have different version of PHP for each. As for .htaccess Apache will read it per directory basis, or you can set the directives globally in apache config file

Comment: @MonkeyZeus : I just want answer to my question as 'YES' or 'NO'

Comment: Oh, .htaccess is not what would be considered as an INI file. It is used by apache module, not by php interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` environment variable is not related to per-directory settings, it does something entirely different. Most Linux distributions build software packages in such a way that settings are kept in different files, so it's easier to install and uninstall individual packages. So this variable is just a trick to split the main configuration file into an undetermined number of separate files inside a directory:

```
/etc/php.d/
```

> how the setting made in one environment(i.e. CLI) has effect in an entirely different environment(i.e. SAPI)?

It doesn't. The Apache module will not read the FastCGI settings just like Apache will not read IIS settings.

Comment: Can you please answer my question at URL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050038/does-the-term-ini-files-mean-configuration-files-parsed-after-php-ini-or-the Please do read my comment to @mario