# Does the term 'INI files' mean configuration files parsed after 'php.ini' or the '.user.ini-style INI files' like '.htaccess' files?

Tags: php, .htaccess, configuration-files, ini, php-ini

I'm using **PHP 7.2.8**.

I've installed PHP using the latest version of **XAMPP** package which has also installed **Apache/2.4.34 (Win32)**

I come across the following text from the [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php#configuration.file.per-user) :

> In addition to the main `php.ini` file, PHP scans for INI files in each
>   directory, starting with the directory of the requested PHP file, and
>   working its way up to the current document root (as set in
>   `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`). In case the PHP file is outside the
>   document root, only its directory is scanned.

The above text has created the following doubt in my mind which is as follows :

What the term used **'INI files'** in the above text is referring to?

Whether it refers to the **'.ini files'** present in a directory which(*the directory*) is set at compile time by setting the `--with-config-file-scan-dir` option, optionally, by an environment variable `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` at run time or the **'.user.ini-style INI files'** like **'.htaccess'** files?

Comment: This whole manual section is titled ".user.ini files". And if you read past the cited excerpt, that's all this section is about. // `.htaccess` is just a marginal note there.

Comment: @mario : If such is the case then as per my knowledge '.user.ini-style files' i.e. '.htaccess' files in my case as I'm using Apache web server are going to be used by Apache only, PHP has nothing to do with them. But the statement from manual clearly says that "In addition to the main php.ini file, PHP scans for INI files in each directory...". So, because of this thing the confusion has created in my mind. Please clear it. Thank You.

Comment: I suggest you try it out.

Comment: I suspect you're overthinking it all. As Mario points out, this manual page is about **.user.ini** files and those are the only INI files that paragraph refers to. It just doesn't explicitly say "**.user.ini** files" again and again because it's clear from context. On the other side, `.htaccess` are configuration files for the Apache web server and they are not INI files at all, they don't even have the syntax of an INI file (just look at all those nested angle brackets). IMHO the reference to `.htaccess` should be removed from main paragraph and rewritten as a foot note.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález : Tell me whether the '.htaccess file'(in case of running PHP as Apache module) is a '.user.ini-style INI file' or not?

Comment: "These files are processed only by the CGI/FastCGI SAPI." should already have cleared it up. -- No offense, but I think most of your confusion stems from selective citations. And if you're using mod_php, then this whole manual part is of no concern to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> … PHP scans for INI files in each directory …

This whole [manual section](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php#configuration.file.per-user) is only about **`.user.ini`** files.

- The format is equivalent to the main `php.ini`
- This only applies to CGI/FCGI/FPM setups.

> … in my case as I'm using Apache web server …

- No relevancy to Apache/mod_php configurations.
- The `.htaccess` config file and `php_flag`/`php_value` directives are **not** INI-style.
- As you already know, PHP itself doesn't read them. (Well, indirectly. Apache parses them.)

> Tell me whether the '.htaccess file'(in case of running PHP as Apache module) is a '.user.ini-style INI file' or not?

- It's not.

> `--with-config-file-scan-dir` … `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR`

- Does also have no relevancy to `.user.ini` nor `.htaccess` files.
- This is used for auxilliary php.ini includes (e.g. module loading/settings, such as `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-gettext.ini` / even XAMPP should have something like this)

Comment: Please check the last statement of the first paragraph on the page titled '.user.ini  files' from PHP Manual. It says, "If you are running PHP as Apache module, use .htaccess files for the same effect.". It means the 'configuration INI files on a per-directory basis' i.e. '.user.ini files' and '.htaccess(in Apache module)' files are used for the same effect, then there should be some relation between them. Am I understanding it correctly? If yes, please explain that relation to me and if no, please explain what does mean by 'for the same effect' then.

Comment: The only relation is the "per-directory usage". Nothing more. They're different things. `.htaccess` != `.user.ini`. Don't pick out single marginal notes to construe additional implications.

Comment: If you think the manual page confusing, you can file a bug report so the .htaccess note gets removed there.

Comment: Yes, actually the text text from manual is too much confusing. I don't understand why did they mention the term '.htaccess' files on the page which is relevant only to INI configuration files i.e. '.user.ini-style files'

Comment: You are saying that `.htaccess != .user.ini`. Today, I noticed a line from the **php.ini** file on my laptop. The line is : `; Name for user-defined php.ini (.htaccess) files. 
Default is ".user.ini"; user_ini.filename = ".user.ini"`
So, my question is if `.htaccess` and `.user.ini` files are different in nature then why the text from `php.ini` file indicates that they are same? You can also refer the latest `php.ini` Git(suggested by **PHP Manual**) for the same. There also you will see same the text I quoted from the `php.ini` file from my machine. This has again created confusion now

Comment: `.htaccess` is very relevant in the document. It's mentioned because it is the alternative to provide the very same feature explained in this section of the manual when mod_php is your SAPI. But it should be a foot note.